# Can't toggle child views inside parent layout in a ListView - focus issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences

### Issue

The gif image says it all. I have a `ListView` where each item is a `LinearLayout`. This parent layout holds some text and a `CheckBox`.

I want the checkbox to toggle itself when the `LinearLayout` gets pressed. This is not what happens, though - see below:

[image: separate childs]

The `LinearLayout` acts on its own, without toggling the checkbox. I can change the CheckBox state manually, but that has no effect on the parent state.

### Some code

My child `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    />
```

My parent `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

### Things I tried

As I read somewhere `CheckBox` has to be non-`focusable`. I tried making it non-`clickable` as well, because I don't want two separate click areas - I want the box to toggle when I click the whole `LinearLayout`. The result is that I can still click on `LinearLayout`, but it has **no effect** on the checkbox.

I've also been messing around with `android:duplicateParentState` (on child) and `android:addStatesFromChildren` (on parent), but I might just not have found the right combination of states.

What can I do? I'm really stuck on this.

### Things you might need to know

E.g., why I can't set a listener.

I'm extending `ActionBarActivity` and have a `PreferenceFragment`.

I don't have much runtime control over items in this list, because they are handled by the `PreferenceFragment`. Each row gets inflated in the listview according to my xml/preferences.xml, and I do nothing about it. As with any preference list, each item has its own native listener to edit my `SharedPreference`. You can see the clicked item to unlock preferences below that have a dependency on it. Again, I do nothing about it and *can't* override the custom behaviour just to toggle checkboxes and switches.

I just set a handmade layout (the one we are talking about) for the single general preference row (there's a proper style attribute for this). So I can control XML attributes of both the row container and the checkboxes, but not so much from java. I think I need a XML solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make the LinearLayout "clickable" and then in your `onClickListener` for that layout, have it toggle the Checkbox `setChecked` state.

It really shouldn't matter if you have two "different" overlapping click "areas" that do the same function. If the LinearLayout consumes the event before it propagates to its child, which it should, then you should never have a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not have a Listener for the `LinearLayout`. These are preferences, and the list gets populated from items in preferences.xml (which is not what we are talking about). The rightmost widget could be a `CheckBox`, or a `Switch`, or even null for other kinds of preferences. Moreover, click events are handled by the PreferenceFragment and set the SharedPreferences() accordingly, which I can not do by hand.

Comment: The layout I'm dealing with is the one that defines the single preference row, and gets inflated by my `PreferenceFragment` according to preferences.xml. I can't override the actual listener for the single row.

Comment: you need to post more code then. You can make a LinearLayout clickable and add an `onClickListener` in general, but if you are using `PreferenceFragment` you should still be able to get the `id` in java and set and `onClickListener` for it...

Comment: I am able to, but this overrides the native listener. As you can see in the image, clicking does set the item preference, and unlocks other preferences above (that have a dependency on the item). I'm *not* managing this behaviour. If I set my own listener, I can toggle the checkboxes, but the item loses its ability to change preferences and such (which would be very annoying to implement, that's what PreferenceFragment are for). I was hoping for a XML solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is strictly related to Preferences, which I at first wanted to leave out of the question, to make it simple.

Assuming I have just two checkboxes, what I did was setting a listener for preference state changes:

```
        listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences defaultSP, String key) {

                if (key.equals(PREF_CHECKBOX1)) {
                    CheckBox s = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    s.setChecked(defaultSP.getBoolean(key, false));
                }
                if (key.equals(PREF_CHECKBOX2)) {
                    CheckBox s2 = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
                    s2.setChecked(defaultSP.getBoolean(key, false));
                }
```

Then I set up two different CheckBox widgets, non-`focusable` and non-`clickable`, differing each other for ID, in two separate layout files:

layout/checkbox1.xml

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    />
```

layout/checkbox2.xml

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    />
```

Lastly, each CheckBoxPreference has its own `android:widgetLayout` attribute.

```
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="..."
        android:title="@..."
        android:defaultValue="false" 
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/checkbox1" />

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="..."
        android:title="@..."
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:widgetLayout="@layout/checkbox2" />
```

I couldn't stay with a single shared widget layout, as I wanted, because `findViewById(R.id.checkbox)` in the listener returns only one of the two, indipendently of which item was pressed and of the key value.

It's quite bad, but I couldn't find anything else.